SSLHandshakeException for some Android devices
around 10% users of my app are struggling to use my API (different devices, different Android versions), calls are ending with exception, below is stack trace:
Caused by javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Read error: ssl=0xb4000078ddc5f488: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:100003e8:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_CLOSE_NOTIFY (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:592 0xb4000078ddc88640:0x00000003)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(NativeCrypto.java)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:568)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:896)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.-$$Nest$mprocessDataFromSocket()
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:236)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:218)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
       at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
       at

Can someone advise? API is signed with Lets Encrypt cert, protocol is TSLv1.3
I am using java.net.HttpURLConnection

"different Android versions" -- what is the newest that you are seeing in significant numbers? Android 7.1.1 and older are known to have problems with current Let's Encrypt certs.

TLS 1.3 is only natively supported from Android 10 onwards. What are the android versions that are expierencing this issue?

Well, I am experiencing it for Android 10-14.

The issue happens always or sometimes?

For some users it is permanent. Either it is working or not

Looking at that stack trace, it appears to reflect that the peer is sending a CLOSE_NOTIFY alert, so this is not something that you can directly control. Of course the peer is likely objecting to something you sent in a previous message. It would be nice to match server log entries with these errors and also see server log entries for successful connections to look for the differences. It may still be something related to the issues suggested by the other comments. Can you add details about which servers you connect to in your app, and which connections are throwing this exception?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk - how can I debug it? I am not able to reproduce it neither on emulator nor any device I have...

@CommonsWare will be the expert on that, it does seem like a tremendous challenge. I was just noting that there are two peers involved in this problem, one being your app and the other being the TLS server you're talking to that doesn't like something about the content of your app's TLS handshake messages. You've provided some error information from the app, but that information does not reveal quite enough for me to diagnose the problem. If you can get the error information from the server logs that might provide more clues as to the problem.

While I appreciate the presidential vote of confidence , I am very out of practice on debugging Android SSL issues. The one suggestion I would make: switch to OkHttp and away from HttpURLConnection.
